# error: declaration shadows a variable in the global scope

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, mergesort, cs50

I've been trying to write tideman.c for CS50 ps3. I'm running merge sort, and there is a struct array where each element is composed of two ints. I'm trying to pass that array into a function, but I keep getting the error message: error: declaration shadows a variable in the global scope.
This is my function declaration:

```
void Merge_Sort(pair pairs[], int l, int r)
```

and this is my call:

```
int r = pair_count - 1;
int l = 0;
Merge_Sort(pairs, l, r);
return;
```

pair_count is an int, pairs is the aforementioned array of type pair (two ints). Any help would be really appreciated! The compiler points to an error with the declaration itself. It says that the array pairs has been declared globally earlier, which is true insofar as it was initialized but I don't know how to pass it into a function without this happening. This is the original array's declaration:

```
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put together a [mcve]? You have a global variable with the same name somewhere but we can't see it without a complete example.

Comment: Just updated it @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to change the names of these variables sent as parameters. I think it will work. Please do change the name of pairs to pairs_g.
It should not be a problem for many compilers but may be your compiler do not allow the shadowing variable.

```
int r_g = pair_count - 1;
int l_g = 0;
Merge_Sort(pairs_g, l_g, r_g);
return;
```

Comment: The problem is that my compiler indicates that the array pairs, not the other variables, are the problem, since the other ones are local and not actually global variables.

Comment: You can change the array variable in function also as it is going as reference. It dont need to be same name. 
```
void Merge_Sort(pair pairs_local[], int l, int r)

```

Comment: If it works with changing the parameter name of pairs to pairs_local, please share with us

Comment: It worked!!! Sorry, forgot to let you know but that's why I added your answer as a solution!